# Debug rhodes framework

Tags: eclipse, debugging, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm newbie to ruby and rhomobile. 
I'm debuggind succesffuly using the simulator, I can set breakpoints, etc... All works fine except I can't debug inside the framework code.
How can I debug through the framework code in a rhomobile app? How can I configure rho studio so I can debug inside the framework?
I'm a newbie with ruby and eclipse.

More detailed:
My problem happens when I try to debug functions inside the framework. For example: I put a breakpoint in a model.find(:all). The debugger stops here, but when I want to debug then find method it doesn't enters it, it simply executes and continues in the next instruction. In keys terms, I want to make a step into, but it makes a step over. If it helps you, in edit mode, when I press control+left mouse button over a "Rho::RhoController" in a line like this: "class TestController < Rho::RhoController", it doesn't open /rhodes-3.2.1/lib/framework/rho/rhocontroller.rb, where the source code of this class is.

Comment: Can you tell me how are you able to put the breakpoints in the code? thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install rhostudio, once ure done with that. You need to run your application through Rhosimulator which is a really fast simulator than native blackberry, android & ios simulators.

Please follow these steps :
Select Run » Debug Configurations… from top menu
Find ‘Rhodes Application’ section on the left and add new (or modify existing) configuration
On ‘Common setting’ tab select a project by clicking ‘Browse…’ button next to ‘Project name:’
Select ‘Rho simulator’ as the platform
Click ‘Apply’ and then ‘Debug’

Its good that you have already added breakpoints in your .rb files which you can now view in log in Console window.

Comment: Hi Akshat, hanks. I'm editing my question because my explain doens't fit in a comment.